# XPath expression for finding the current element as well as children

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

With the expression `.//b` I can find all elements *below* the current element with the tag `b`.  If the current element has also a `b` tag, it will not be found.  How can I express that I want to find all the children of the current tag *as well as* the current element itself, in case it matches the given tag name?

Here is some example input xml:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <i>
      <u>one</u>
    </i>
    <b>two</b>
  </b>
  <b>three</b>
  <em>four</em>
</a>
```

If the first element `<b>` is the current element, I want to get all sub elements (i. e. the one containing `two`) and the element itself, but not the element containing `three` (when searching for tags `b`).  When searching for tags `u` I want to get only the one containing `one`.

I've tried `.[name()='b']|.//b` but that's apparently an invalid expression.

I also tried `..//b` but then I not only get the element itself and the one containing `two` but also the one containing `three`.

Is this possible with one XPath expression to get what I want?

*Side note: I'm using this in Python's lxml/etree library but that should make no difference.*

Comment: try using `//b`. Using `.//b` makes no sense. `//b` should bring ou `<b>` elements with everything inside them.

Comment: No, `.//b` makes excellent sense, and its meaning is quite different from `//b`. Wrong information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `descendant-or-self` axis here:

```
descendant-or-self::b
```

Alternatively, you could do this, which is slightly shorter to write...

```
self::b|.//b
```

Comment: I'm using `(.|.//*)[name()='b']` now to avoid doubling the tag name.  But that's essentially your answer.

Comment: Be slightly careful, as `name()` will return any namespace prefix (so, it wouldn't match `my:b` for example. You would use `local-name()` in this instance.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  Actually, I'm using the `ETXPath` class which allows specifying namespaces in so-called Clark notation: `{http://some/weird/uri}tagname`.  But using `name()` still yields the name with the prefix, not the Clark notation :(  Using `descendant-or-self::` works fine with the Clark notation, so I'll stick to this to avoid doubling the tag name.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would definitely go for `descendant-or-self::b` as the expression that's simplest and best expresses the intent. Simplicity in terms of number of constructs is more important than brevity in terms of number of characters. Avoid comparing `name()` against character strings, it's a bad habit which will sometimes cost you dearly in performance.

Comment: Performance is no issue in my case, but in general you are right.  I just want a version which works every time and is as readable as possible.  I agree that the verbose qualifier fits best for this task.